# Do pure NDK Android apps have .dex files?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm curious. Do Android apps written 100% in C or C++ using the manifest to specify a native activity with `android:hasCode="false"` have a .dex file in the apk?

Comment: Why don't you build one, rename APK to ZIP and take a look inside?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev XD...I don't have the NDK installed nor do I know any C or C++ so I figured I'd just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is usually a dex file for auto-generated Java classes:

- BuildConfig
- R (if you have any Android resources)

Comment: I totally forgot about the auto-generated classes. Thanks for the info though.